# ios tableview dynamic prototype doesn't work in storyboard

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitableview, tableview

I'm new to Objective-C and following Apple's tutorial on how to create a simple app with tableView and detailsView:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/SecondiOSAppTutorial/SecondiOSAppTutorial.pdf

I only differed from the instructions by using different names and embedding it into a tabbed app.

I compared my code twice to the one shown in the tutorial and it's the same...

I also searched the web for two days trying to find an answer to this problem. The only thing I found is that a lot of people had problems when trying to use dynamic prototype with storyboards, but, there usually weren't any answers, and if there were they didn't help in my case.

Another thing I found is that neither the viewDidLoad method or the awakeFromNib method are being called when the app loads or the view is shown. I saw other questions about it, but, with no answer.

Would HIGHLY appreciate your help!!

Thanks! 
Shila

**Relevant code:
Data controller initialization:**

```
@interface MMMeetingDataController ()

-(void)initializeDefultDataList;

@end

@implementation MMMeetingDataController

-(void)initializeDefultDataList
{
    NSMutableArray *meetingList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    self.masterMeetingList = meetingList;

    MMMeeting *meeting;

    NSDate *today = [NSDate date];

    meeting = [[MMMeeting alloc] initWithSubject:@"Default" invitees:@"Default" location:@"My Office" date:today];

    [self addMeetingWithSubject:meeting];

}
```

**TableViewController (list):**

```
@implementation MMMeetingsListViewController

-(void)awakeFromNib
{
    [super awakeFromNib];

    self.dataController = [[MMMeetingDataController alloc] init];
}

-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];   
}
```

-- Both of the above functions are not being called in debug...

Comment: How are we supposed to help without your code ?

Comment: Code is same as in the tutorial... This is the more specific location: <https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/SecondiOSAppTutorial/CodeListings/CodeListings.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011318-CH9-SW1> Let me know if you prefer to see my code.

Comment: @shila Telling us you have followed a tutorial and then linking us to a 101 page document won't help much...

Comment: Ok, sorry, I'm new to this... What parts of the code would you like me to add? I have a data controller, the tableView controller and detailesView controller.

Comment: Yes, please add your code (the relevant parts, ie. the parts that differs from the tutorial). Also, check that the proper storyboard is set in the project settings, and that the root view controller of the storyboard has its class set to your custom class.

Comment: My app is running and I can see the tableView (changed it's color to make sure...). The only thing is that I can't see any data even though I initialized my array with default data.

Comment: Post. Your. Code. If you don't we CAN NOT help you. Comments are not supposed to be a chat.

Comment: Posted the code, took me a while..

Comment: @shila can u please show the screen shot of your storyboard?

Answer (score 0):

Open your storyboard, click on your view controller (the yellow circle icon under your table view should be selected, see the screenshot), and make sure the Custom Class field is set to the name of your view controller (`MMMeetingsListViewController`).

[image]

Comment: I debugged the default MasterDetail template provided by apple, and the awakeFromNib is called there. Perhaps because I'm using the tabbed application for some reason the awakeFromNib is not called? Did anyone tried to use it that way with storyboards?

Comment: What do you mean by "tabbed application" ?

Comment: When I created a new project I selected a tabbed application and not Master Details application. I then added a tableView to one of the controllers. I assume somewhere in there is my mistake. Is the right way to do that is choosing a Master Detail application and then embed it in a tab navigation?

Comment: No no. Tabbed application should work fine. Again, if the `awakeFromNib` of your view controller is not called, it means it is not properly set in your storyboard, and iOS instantiate the default `UIViewController` class instead of your own. Maybe add several screenshots of your storyboard to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. Since I was using the tabbed application and added the tableView controller manually, I should have also embedded it in a navigation bar. Once I embedded the tableView controller in a navigation bar problem was solved.